# postgres: how to convert hstore to JSON datatypes

Tags: json, postgresql, hstore

I'm trying to write a migration to convert an existing hstore column to JSON (not JSONB).

I tried different solutions `json USING cast(hstore_column as json)`, some functions found over github, but nothing really worked out.

Main issue is that there's no direct conversion, second is that even if I cast the column to text as an intermediate step I need to change the default column value to json as well.

Anyone already did this?

Comment: did you try hstore_to_json(hstore) ?

Comment: yes but I'm not sure which default value should I set in order to perform the conversion: `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN h_store SET DEFAULT '{}'::JSON` and it refuses to proceed, `SET DEFAULT '{}'` and I'm getting string errors.

Comment: mm, I just dropped the default and apparently it's going, mind writing an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Try `alter table my_table alter column h_store_column type json using hstore_to_json(h_store_column)`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name should do the honours and write an answer, his answer is more complete

Comment: If you have a gist index on that column, you will need to drop it before converting the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use

```
alter table my_table alter column h_store_column type json using hstore_to_json(h_store_column)
```

Of course you will need to drop any defaults set on the column that don't align with the json data type first.